# Apply scroll to a html application

Tags: jquery, html

How can apply scroll bars to the below HTML chat application using jquery, possibilities to add scrollbars to the conversational chat bot.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container"  style="top:45%">
         
            <div class="left">
            <ul class="people">
            <img src="miracle.png" alt="" /> 
            </li>
           </ul>
                    <div class="top">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="search"></a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="people">
             <li class="person" data-chat="person2">
                        <img src="Doris.png" alt="" style="width:15%;height:15%" />
                          <span class="name">Doris</span>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
           
                </div>
          
          
                <div class="right" >
                    <div class="top"><center><span><span class="name">Conversational Help Desk Agent</span></span></center></div>
                    <div class="chat" style="overflow:scroll"  data-chat="person2">
            <div id="hell1" class="bubble you"></div>
            <div id="hell" class="bubble me"></div> 
                    </div>
           
                    <div class="write">
        
           <form>
        
           <input id="m" autocomplete="off" name="SEND" />
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="write-link send" id="send"></a>
            </br><br>
        
            </form>
        
          </div>
          
                </div>
               <div id='gt'></div>
            </div>
        </div>`
```

This is the entire code which I am using for my chat-bot application

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use jQuery for this when it can be done easily by css?

In CSS solution you have to set specific height on the wrapper and allow overflow-y

```
.chat {
   height: 350px;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

That will force the window to add scroller in case content is bigger than 350px.

If you have some other code ready post the code here or create fiddle so we can see exactly what are you trying to achieve.

jQuery way would be

```
$('.chat').css({'height': '350px', 'overflow-y': 'auto'})
```

Comment: I applied snip which shared by you to my code but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please update your question with the complete code after an update so I can see where is the problem.